# How to Implement Autocomplete for Association in simple_form in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently building a book handling project in Rails 6. There are two models `Book` and `Categories`, Category can contain many books but a book can only belong to a single category. I'm currently using `simple_form` `f.association` to make the form association which creates a dropdown menu of Categories.

`new.html.erb` in Book

```
    <section class="mt-8">
    <%= simple_form_for @book, defaults: { input_html: {class: 'form-input mt-1'}, wrapper_html: {class: 'flex flex-col my-2'}} do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description, input_html: {class: 'form-textarea'} %>
    <%= f.input :amazon_url %>
    <%= f.association :category, collection: Category.all.order(name: :asc),input_html: {class: 'form-select'} %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Create New Book', class: 'mt-4 p-2 rounded-md bg-gray-400' %>
    <% end %>
</section>
```

I want the Categories list to be an autocomplete input. How do I implement this in Rails 6.  I have tried various libraries but they all are outdated.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue as you, seems strange that such a common use case doesn't have an obvious solution. I hear ya about all the libraries being outdated. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I figured out a way using chosen, I'll post the solution after I reach home

Comment: I found your solution https://aswinmohan.me/posts/implementing-autocomplete-in-rails-6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found the Choices library. It's entirely javascript based and due to the webpack asset compilation of Rails 6, works seamlessly.

I have written a blog post on the same. https://aswinmohan.me/posts/implementing-autocomplete-in-rails-6/

Comment: Turbolinks might not be used, therefor perhaps better to use one of these: document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => { ... });
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { ... });

Answer (score 1):

[Chosen](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) has support for Rails 6.